# Spark Checkpointing Non-Streaming - Checkpoint files can be used in subsequent job run or driver program

Tags: apache-spark, checkpointing

This text from an interesting article: http://www.lifeisafile.com/Apache-Spark-Caching-Vs-Checkpointing/

" ... Checkpointing stores the rdd physically to hdfs and destroys the lineage that created it. The checkpoint file won’t be deleted even after the Spark application terminated. **Checkpoint files can be used in subsequent job run or driver program.** Checkpointing an RDD causes double computation because the operation will first call a cache before doing the actual job of computing and writing to the checkpoint directory. ..."

I seem to remember reading elsewhere that checkpointed files were only for the a Job or shared Jobs in a given Spark App.

Looking for clarification and how a new App could use the checkpoint directory, as I did not think that was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I seem to remember reading elsewhere that checkpointed files were only
>   for the Job or shared Jobs in a given Spark App.

Spark will not purge the `checkpoint` directory even after stopping the `SparkContext`. We can turn on auto cleanup by setting below propert:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.cleanCheckpoints", "true")
```

> Looking for clarification and how a new App could use the checkpoint
>   directory, as I did not think that was possible.

To reuse the checkpointed dataset again we can follow below steps:

1. **Start context 1 and checkpoint dataset:**

```
// Setting logger on for ReliableRDDCheckpointData
scala> import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
scala> Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark.rdd.ReliableRDDCheckpointData").setLevel(Level.INFO)

// Note application ID
scala> spark.sparkContext.applicationId
res1: String = local-1567969150914

// Set checkpoint Dir
scala> spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("/tmp/spark/checkpoint")

// File system localtion
Users-Air:checkpoint User$ pwd
/tmp/spark/checkpoint
Users-Air:checkpoint User$ ls -lrth
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 User  wheel    64B Sep  8 15:00 7aabcb46-e707-49dd-8893-148a162368d5

// Create Dataframe
scala> val df = spark.range(3).withColumn("random", rand())
scala> df.show
+---+------------------+
| id|            random|
+---+------------------+
|  0|0.8517439782779789|
|  1| 0.288880016535247|
|  2|0.7027831376739603|
+---+------------------+

scala> df.schema
res5: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(id,LongType,false), StructField(random,DoubleType,false))

//Check point 
scala> df.checkpoint
19/09/08 15:02:22 INFO ReliableRDDCheckpointData: Done checkpointing RDD 7 to file:/tmp/spark/checkpoint/7aabcb46-e707-49dd-8893-148a162368d5/rdd-7, new parent is RDD 8
res6: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [id: bigint, random: double]

// New RDD saved in checkpoint directory /tmp/spark/checkpoint/7aabcb46-e707-49dd-8893-148a162368d5/rdd-7
Users-Air:7aabcb46-e707-49dd-8893-148a162368d5 User$ cd rdd-7/
Users-Air:rdd-7 User$ ls -lrth
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 User  wheel     4B Sep  8 15:02 part-00000
-rw-r--r--  1 User  wheel   163B Sep  8 15:02 part-00002
-rw-r--r--  1 User  wheel   163B Sep  8 15:02 part-00001
-rw-r--r--  1 User  wheel   163B Sep  8 15:02 part-00003

// Stop context 
scala> spark.stop
scala> :quit
```

2. **Start new Context 2 and read the checkpointed dataset**

```
// Initilaized New Context 
scala> spark.sparkContext.applicationId
res0: String = local-1567969525656
```

[SparkContext.checkpointFile](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L1359) is a `protected[spark]` method so we need to create class under `org.apache.spark` package

```
scala> :paste -raw
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

package org.apache.spark
object RecoverCheckpoint {
  import scala.reflect.ClassTag
  import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
  def recover[T: ClassTag](sc: SparkContext, path: String): RDD[T] = {
    sc.checkpointFile[T](path)
  }
}
```

Now **recover** the Checkpointed RDD as `RDD[InternalRow]` using above `RecoverCheckpoint` class

```
// Path from first context
scala> val checkPointFilePath = "/tmp/spark/checkpoint/7aabcb46-e707-49dd-8893-148a162368d5/rdd-7"
scala> import org.apache.spark.RecoverCheckpoint
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
scala> val RecoveredRDD = RecoverCheckpoint.recover[InternalRow](spark.sparkContext, checkPointFilePath)

// RDD is recovered as RDD[InternalRow]
scala> RecoveredRDD
res2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow] = ReliableCheckpointRDD[0] at recover at <console>:34

// Count matches with original
RecoveredRDD.count
res3: Long = 3
```

To convert recovered RDD to Dataset creating `RecoverCheckpointRDDToDF` class

```
// Need to convert RDD[InternalRow] to DataFrame
scala> :paste -raw
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

// Creating Dataframe from RDD[InternalRow]
package org.apache.spark.sql
object RecoverCheckpointRDDToDF {
  import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
  import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
  import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow
  import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
  def createDataFrame(spark: SparkSession, catalystRows: RDD[InternalRow], schema: StructType): DataFrame = {
    spark.internalCreateDataFrame(catalystRows, schema)
  }
}
```

Finally, use the `RecoverCheckpointRDDToDF` and get the dataset back

```
// Schema should be know
val df_schema = StructType(List(StructField("id",LongType,false), StructField("random",DoubleType,false)))
df_schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(id,LongType,false), StructField(random,DoubleType,false))

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.RecoverCheckpointRDDToDF
scala> val df = RecoverCheckpointRDDToDF.createDataFrame(spark, RecoveredRDD, df_schema)

scala> df.show
+---+------------------+
| id|            random|
+---+------------------+
|  0|0.8517439782779789|
|  1| 0.288880016535247|
|  2|0.7027831376739603|
+---+------------------+

// Same as first context

// Stop context
scala> spark.stop
scala> :quit
```

Comment: ok, i am going to try that. gosh, i also read i am pretty sure only available in same context. ok that that is not so. awfully convoluted. when would we do this given we can use spark bucketBy between Apps?

Comment: Good answer, buf I will not be implementing it unless you can convince me.

Comment: @thebluephantom: :) tbh, I haven't put any use case in production with this technique but this seems to be a legit approach. What are your doubts?

Comment: I explored this for one of the use case while back but was not comfortable.

Comment: hard yakka. bucketBy seens easier to me by far, but it is a tricky topic so I am impressed.

Comment: @ SMaZ..I had some problem way back related to checkpointing. I will try above options. It's informative. Could you please take a look at below question also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53647124/reading-from-hive-table-and-updating-same-table-in-pyspark-using-checkpoint

Comment: I am an architect as well, and the way I see it, we would not use this approach. Too hard. This aspect spark.conf.set("spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.cleanCheckpoints", "true") is indeed a clue, I think we missed this and assumed the various blurbs. Once again, great stuff.

Comment: @SMaZ.. I was trying to code above in pyspark but was not succeeded. I score null in Scala. Do you have Pyspark version as well for  above code or Do let me know in case I have to raise a question. Thanks

Comment: @vikrantrana Sorry , I don’t have python version of it. In Pyspark `checkpointFile` method is exposed as `sc._checkpointFile(path, deserializer) that` will give you `ReliableChckpointRDD`. That might be way to go. However, not sure on how to do next step.