# Spark avoid execution of the entire query each time

Tags: database, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have query that does a  moving average over the beginning of time on data found in mysql db. Then I need to execute that query
every day to use the previous day's value.

Instead of querying my database everytime I am using checkpoint to store the latest date computed so far.
Then I am restoring the checkpoint to get the dataframe but I am getting all the data I used before including the latest date stored in a dataframe.

I just need a method to not have to re-execute my query on the whole mysql db and instead use the latest date's input or is that doable and recommended in spark.

```
df.checkpoint
RecoverCheckpoint.recover
```

I do not know if that is a good method since checkpoint is used for fault tolerance. Is there another way to achieve this?

Ref:

[Spark Checkpointing Non-Streaming - Checkpoint files can be used in subsequent job run or driver program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57840083/spark-checkpointing-non-streaming-checkpoint-files-can-be-used-in-subsequent-j)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may like this https://dzone.com/articles/what-are-spark-checkpoints-on-dataframes as you will discover that for iterative algorithms this is also a necessary aspect. Some odd things to get to grips with.

In all honesty I would re-query as you refer to my original question and I would do things simple still. Good answer but no way would I implement that. You see the issue you are getting yourself.

Comment: would you say that storing today's date in a db (instead of checkpoint) and then run the sql query based on that date be a good idea?

Comment: easier and if you master that ans then leave some other person will need to get up to speed. maybe bucketBy is a better option